# PostgreSQL 9.6 Partitioned table and grails 2.5.6 weird operation under tomcat7 or tomcat8

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, grails, tomcat7, tomcat8

I have this configuration on my project:
 - grails 2.5.6 and hibernate4 (4.3.8.1)
 - PostgreSQL 9.6 with partitioned tables (we used the pg_partman extension to do the partitioning)
 - Deployed in tomcat 7

We were thinking about upgrading tomcat7 to tomcat8 or tomcat8.5. And now it comes the problem, with tomcat7 all is working properly. But deploying the same war to tomcat8 we get this error when we try to save a record in the partitioned table:

```
2018-09-06 17:33:14,976 [lecturaQueueMessageJmsListenerContainer-1] ERROR The database returned no natively generated identity value; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value
2018-09-06 17:33:14,977 [lecturaQueueMessageJmsListenerContainer-1] ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure  - HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in xxx.Lectura entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
2018-09-06 17:33:15,125 [lecturaQueueMessageJmsListenerContainer-1] ERROR Lectura$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c61146fe.queueMessage  - Exception raised in message listener
org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'queueMessage' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in xx.Lectura entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at grails.plugin.jms.listener.adapter.PersistenceContextAwareListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(PersistenceContextAwareListenerAdapter.groovy:45)
    at grails.plugin.jms.listener.adapter.LoggingListenerAdapter.onMessage(LoggingListenerAdapter.groovy:49)
    at grails.plugin.jms.listener.adapter.PersistenceContextAwareListenerAdapter.onMessage(PersistenceContextAwareListenerAdapter.groovy:33)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in xx.Lectura entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    ... 4 more
```

I guess the problem is related to hibernate. Does it make sense? Does anyone know why I'm getting this error on tomcat8 and not getting it on tomcat7?

Reading about this, I see a lot of people talking about getting the null id error, but it shouldn't work neither on tomcat7 nor tomcat8.
That's why I don't understand why is working properly in my case on tomcat7 but not working on tomcat8 or tomcat8.5.

PS. Just to add more confusion, if I deploy the war on tomcat8 but under windows it works properly. But if I deploy it under linux (official docker alpine 
 tomcat 8 container) it through the error of null id when It saves a record.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your database is returning a record with id null.
Have you tried to execute a raw sql query and check what is returning?
You could try do like this:

```
// Get sessionFactory injecting in a service or from ApplicationContext
final session = sessionFactory.currentSession
final String query = 'select * from my_table';
final queryResults = session.createSQLQuery(query).list();
// Inspect your result list
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem happens just when I insert a record, not on a select. And it just happens when I insert on a partitioned table.

Comment: Oh, sorry for not helping you. Maybe you could create a small application reproducing the issue and post the link here (git or gist)